# Allow upvote a post for a second time after a long time has passed

Tags: feature-request, voting

I already asked the question whether it was a good idea to be able to upvote a question for the 2nd time.

The main reasons not to (iirc) was to not encourage votebots and vote circles.

Would it be a good idea to be able to have a 2nd vote for every 100 reputation (for instance) and only be able to upvote the same question/answer after 6 months when you used your 1st vote (for that post)?

From time to time I get back to a question where I already upvoted and a 2nd vote this expensive I would only cast if I really really really like the question/answer...

Comment: Just use bounty in that case?

Comment: Which problem would this solve?

Comment: So like how a banana republic dictator stuffs the ballot box in every election and still calls it "free and fair"?  I'd personally get to vote eight thousand times, sounds exhausting.  Lets not.  Bounties are the American way, when you are rich you have more influence.  I've seen them abused as well, but it is quite rare.

Comment: The main reason not to is because we need to make way more effort to make it clear to people voting is not a reward and punishment system. Making it way easier to use votes as a reward and punishment system is the exact opposite direction.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First, as with any proposal regarding voting there should be at least a modicum on effort of thinking how would a specific proposal affect the balance between upvotes and downvotes, and I think this one does nothing to address this.

#### But even if we changed "upvoting" for "voting" in your proposal:

Voting is meant to be an indicator what the community thinks about the quality of a particular post. It is an aggregate of individual opinions.

The opinion of all users is worth exactly the same, and a vote from a user with 15 points affects the score exactly in the same way than a vote from a user with 1.000.000 points.

This proposal would make it possible for users with more reputation to cast additional votes (and the more rep one has, the more likely one would be tempted to use this "feature"), and thus would make their opinion on quality to be worth more than the opinion of lower reputation users.

Any user that could vote twice on a post would have twice the say on a post quality than a user that could only have voted once (or that only wanted to vote once).

If what you want is to reward an specific answer, just use bounties. Those are very visible and are a practical way for transferring reputation directly.